# one or more multiply defined symbols found error - simple

Tags: c++

I'm trying to deal with this problem for some time and I can't seem to find the solution. I'm getting error:
    one or more multiply defined symbols found
I faced this error while dealing with something more complicated, but even simple examples like this one don't work for me. Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include "defs.cpp"

int main()
{
string a = "A";
printIt(a);
}
```

, and here is my defs.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"

void printIt(string a)
{
cout << a;
}
```

, and this is my header.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printIt(string a);
```

I guess this is something trivial, but please don't rage if you think this is duplicate, because I'm a beginner and I didn't understand more complicated examples. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: `#include "defs.cpp"` including translation units is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Can you give me a further explanation and a possible fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see `#include "defs.cpp"` you need to get very suspicious: `cpp` files are not meant to be included; only header files are designed for that.

Instead of including a cpp file, write a header for it. It appears that you have a suitable header already - your `header.h`, which contains the forward declaration of `printIt`:

```
void printIt(string a);
```

Now replace `#include defs.cpp` with `#include "header.h"`, and compile your code. This should fix the problem.

Compiling this depends on the system where you are trying it out. On UNIX-like systems, you would write

```
g++ defs.cpp main.cpp
./a.out
```

Comment: Including header file fixed it. I thought that I need to connect defs and header somehow in header. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `#include` a CPP file. Only include header files containing the function prototype definitions. If no such header file exists, put the function prototype in your program (for eg. in file where `main` is written).

In your case, you are including (directly/indirectly) the CPP file which is having the **definition** of the function. Since same definition is compiled through CPP files, compiler is putting them into `.OBJ` file (known as *intermediate* or *object* files). The linker finally attempts to combine these Object files, and says some function (symbol) is multiply defined.

Answer (score 0):

In `main.cpp` you are including `defs.cpp` which includes a definition of `printIt`. So the translation unit corresponding to `main.cpp` defines `printIt`.

However, you are also compiling `defs.cpp` which defines `printIt`. `defs.cpp`s corresponding translation unit thus defines `printIt` too.

Combining both into one program would lead to multiple (yet equivalent) definitions of this function which is forbidden by the ODR. Remove the `#include` directive and your program should link correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are including:-

```
#include "defs.cpp"
```

and due to this there are multiple definitions of method printIt.

These are some basic rules:-

1) You must always include only header files in your source files. Even then you have to make sure header files are included only once because if it is included more than once then there *could* again be problem of multiple definition.To protect against that your header files should contain header gaurds.

2) C++ always adheres with single definition rule. However , you can have as many declaratons as possible as long as all declarations are consistent.